# Handling a resource effectively using auto pointers

Tags: c++

I have a code which looks like this:

```
class Parent
{
 auto_ptr<Resource> ptr2Resc;
 public: void parentMethod(int i )
{
 SomeOtherClass someOthrPtr = new SomeOtherClass(ptr2Resc); 
}
};

The ctor of SomeOtherClass:
SomeOtherClass(auto_ptr<Resource> ptrRes);
```

So now when i call parentMethod, the auto_ptr gets swapped and the ptr2Resc is dellocated. My C++ code doesn't support TR1 or Boost. 
So whats the best way to have the ptr2Resc deallocated during the Parent Class destructor, and not when it is passed as a parameter. Can i pass it as a reference to auto_ptr to the SomeOtherClass ctor?

Thanks

Comment: Question: Do you _really_ want an `auto_ptr` or some other smart pointer (e.g. ` shared_ptr`?

Comment: "Can i pass it as a reference to auto_ptr to the SomeOtherClass ctor?" -- this is trivial to try... why not try it and report back with the result?

Comment: Why don't you change the constructor of SomeClass to take *normal* pointer as you don't intend to transfer the ownership?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the quote from Josuttis book regarding passing auto_ptr by reference:

> You might think about passing
>   auto_ptrs by reference instead.
>   However, passing auto_ptrs by
>   reference confuses the concept of
>   ownership. A function that gets an
>   auto_ptr by reference might or might
>   not transfer ownership. Allowing an
>   auto_ptr to pass by reference is very
>   bad design and you should always avoid
>   it

As I said in my comment, if you do not intend to transfer the ownnership, you can simply change the constructor of `SomeClass` to take a raw pointer.

Comment: Changing it to raw pointer is what i intended to do. But i wanted to see if its okay for passing it as reference.

Comment: No don't do it..today it might work..but if tomorrow somebody creates a local copy of the passed auto_ptr reference you will be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

`std::auto_ptr<Resource>` has an **ugly** copy constructor. Make copy of the `boost::shared_ptr` implementation and use it (your copy).